# Javascript: Creating a persistently bound function

Tags: javascript, binding, prototype, this

I realise a question like this is asked pretty frequently (I've probably read every one of them over the past few days trying to understand how to fix this) - but in this case, while I'm fairly confident I know why this is happening, I'm struggling to implement an actual solution.

I'm building a small application using Node.js but having trouble with creating an object with prototype functions that won't lose their binding when they're passed around.

Here's what I have so far:

**foo.js**

```
var Foo = module.exports = function(server) {
    this.server = server;
    // some other stuff
};

Foo.prototype.send = function(data) {
    server.doStuff(data);
};

Foo.prototype.sendData = function(data) {
    // do stuff with data;
    this.send(data);
};
```

**bar.js**

```
var Bar = module.exports = function() {
    this.dataStore = // data store connection;
};

Bar.prototype.getSomething(data, callback) {
    this.dataStore.get(data, function(err, response) {
        callback(response);
    });
};
```

**main.js**

```
var Foo = require('./foo');
var Bar = require('./bar');
var aFoo = new Foo(server);
var aBar = new Bar();

// at some point do:
aBar.getSomething(data, aFoo.sendData);
```

As you can probably imagine, passing that aFoo.sendData function for use as a callback causes it to lose its binding to aFoo, so it is unable to find the 'send' function on Foo.

How would I modify Foo so that sendData maintains its binding to Foo? Is there a better way to structure this code so that this isn't necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simple wrap the call to aFoo.sendData in an anonymous function:

```
aBar.getSomething(data, function () {
    aFoo.sendData();
});
```

Because your referencing `aFoo.sendData`, the reference to `this` inside `sendData` is no longer `aFoo`. When using the anonymous function, you're not referencing the function; you're simply invoking it as a method on the `aFoo` instance, so `this` is still `aFoo`.

Comment: Great! This seems to partially work; but I need to pass 'data' to sendData, which means I have to actually use: 
aBar.getSomething(data, function(data) { aFoo.sendData(data); } (as far as I can tell) - which seems slightly unnecessary when I'm already passing data as a parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tom: It's a tiny bit of a pain, but it's extremely common throughout JavaScript. If you've got a lot of parameters, and you don't want to retype them all, you could do `function () {sendData.apply(aFoo, arguments); }`, which will automatically populate the parameters of `sendData` with any arguments provided to the anonymous function (although, technically speaking, if your arguments are getting that long, you should be passing them as a single object rather than individually....).

Comment: Cheers for the very helpful response, starting to make a lot more sense now!