# confusion over how "softBind" function works

Tags: javascript, function, binding, prototype, this

I'm currently studying javascript by following the "you dont know js" series.

In section "[this & object prototype](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)", the author came up with an way to soft bind `this`.

However, I am extremely confused by the code. So I was wondering if someone could kindly explain it to me, steps by steps, what the code really does?

```
//step 1: if "softBind" property does not exist on `Function.prototye`

if (!Function.prototype.softBind) {

    //step 2: create a property named "softBind" on "Function.prototype" and assign to "softBind" the following function 

    Function.prototype.softBind = function(obj) {

        //step 3: what is the point of assigning "this" to the variable "fn"?
        //what does "this" represent at this point in time?

        var fn = this,

            //step 4: I understand that "arguments" is an array-like object, i.e. "arguments" is not a true array. 
            //But you can convert "arguments" to an true array by using "[].slice.call(arguments)". 
            //The thing I dont understand here is, why the 1? 
            //I understand it tells "slice" method to start slicing at index 1, but why 1? 
            //And what is the purpose of "curried" variable? 

            curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),

            bound = function bound() {

                //step 5: I understand what "apply" function does

                return fn.apply(

                    //step 6: I dont really understand how "!this" works. 

                    (!this ||

                        //step 7: utterly confused...   
                         
                        (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
                            this === window) ||
                        (typeof global !== "undefined" &&
                            this === global)

                    //step 8: if the above statements evaluates to "true", then use "obj", 
                    //otherwise, use "this"

                    ) ? obj : this,

                    //step 9: can't I write "curried.concat(arguments)" instead?
                    //why the convoluted syntax?

                    curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
                );
            };

        //step 10: Why assign the "fn.prototype" as the prototype to "bound.prototype"?

        bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
        return bound;
    };
}
```

I'm very sorry for the long question, but I thought instead of dividing the question into several posts, it is more convenient if they are put into one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**step 3: what is the point of assigning "this" to the variable "fn"?**

The value of `this` holds a pointer to the currently executing function object. Only function objects can be held, so only things actually created through new() or equivalent notation. This can be useful for passing a reference to an outer object to an inner object created within said outer object.

Here's a minimal example:

```
function fn1() {
    var x = this;  // x = fn1.
    this.u = 5;
    function fn2() {
        this.u = 10;
        console.log(this.u); // Prints the member of fn2.
        console.log(x.u); // Prints the member of fn1.
    };
    var W = new fn2();
}
var V = new fn1();
```

The output should be:

```
10
5
```

First, an object of type `fn1` is created called `V`. It has a member variable `u` holding the value `5`. Then, we create an object of type `fn2` called `W` within `fn1`. It **also** has a member variable `u`, but here it holds the value `10`. If we wanted to `print` the value of `V.u` within `W`, then we need a pointer to `V`. Calling `this.u` within `W` would output its u value (10), which is not what we want. So we define a variable `x` within the scope of the class `fn1`, holding the `this` pointer for us. Now it's possible to access the members of `fn1` within `fn2`.

**Step 4**

The first argument is the object being bound to. You don't want to pass that to the function being bound, that would break its functionality, for it does not expect an extra argument prepended to its normal list of arguments. So, the first argument has to be removed.

**step 6: I dont really understand how "!this" works.**

`!this` is simply a way of checking whether `this` is defined. If it is not, then the value will be `true`. Otherwise, since `this`
 would be an object (which evaluate to `true` when cast to a boolean), then it is `false`.

**step 7: utterly confused...**

Here, the original author checks if `this` is equal to either `window`, or `global`. Note; In modern browsers, checking for just `window` is enough, but IE exists (as do non-browser javascript environments). So, the full statement evaluates to this thing:

*If I am not called from within an object, or if I'm called from the object `window` or `global`, then return the object `softbind` was created with. Otherwise, return the object I was called from*

Note that this is **exactly** what the author of the original article wants. When a library function is called with this special binding, then we can be sure that whatever the library does; it can't access the `global` context through the use of the `this` variable. But, it can access any other object, allowing you to interface with the library.

**step 9: can't I write "curried.concat(arguments)" instead?**

`Curried` holds all arguments the original `softbind` function was called with, except for the first argument. `arguments` , at this point, is not equal to `arguments` in the earlier call. Here, it refers to the arguments the bound function is called with, not those it was bound with. This line integrates the two sets of arguments, allowing you to provide default arguments. The trick used here is to concatenate the arguments, e.g. Suppose your function has default arguments `[1,2,3,4]` and you supply `[5,6]`:

`[1,2,3,4].concat([5,6])` produces `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Why not simply concatenate, and use the prototype? Arrays are passed by reference in javascript, so this will keep `curried` the same, while concatenating `arguments` to the call. Equivalently, you could write this:

```
curried2 = curried.concat(arguments);
return fn.apply(
(.....)
curried2);
```

Admittedly, the terseness does not help the understandability of this example. Simply re-naming arguments to calledArguments and `curried` (an advanced math term not relevant to the explanation) to be `defaultArguments` and using a simple `for` loop over each argument would be far easier to understand, if a little more verbose. I guess the author wanted to be fancy.

**step 10: Why assign the "fn.prototype" as the prototype to "bound.prototype"?**

Go up a bit on the article to the part where the author talks about the default `bind` function and how it works: basically, the end result of replacing the `prototype` back with the default prototype during the function call means that when your `softbind` enabled function is called with the `new` operator `this` will be set to itself, rather than the default bound object. `prototype` will not work when simply calling the bound function.

It also enables *inheritance*, meaning that creating things for a `softbind` enabled function using its `prototype` will not have that prototype be overruled by that of `softbind` when it is bound. (That would make softbind incompatible with prototypes). Instead, **both** prototypes are used.

Also see [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5ovl09/understanding_functionprototypebind_polyfill/).

**A word of warning**

We're extending the language with new features here. Features that aren't exactly necessary, and are largely concerned with semantics. If you're just interested in learning the language, this really goes way too far, you don't exactly need special binding semantics. Worse, it can be confusing if `this` does not behave in a way you expect it to.

**A simpler alternative**

Enable *strict mode*. Now `this` will default to `undefined` whenever it points to the global object. Prevents the problem this convoluted code is trying to solve (by usually resulting in errors from functions trying to access member variables or functions of `undefined`), while at the same time being far easier to use, and at the same time it will complain about a lot of syntax that is valid regular javascript, but a bug in any normal use-case. Also see the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) about it. It will catch a lot of potential errors for you instead of silently doing nonsensical things.

**Another alternative**

`bind` tries to resolve 'losing' the object when you pass a member function of it to another function, such as `setTimeout`. Another way of doing it is by using an anonymous function. Instead of using (soft) binding, assuming `obj` is an object holding a function `fn` being passed a parameter `param`;

```
setTimeout(obj.fn(param), 500);
```

You can use:

```
setTimeout(function(param){obj.fn(param);}, 500);
```

Which avoids the problem through a layer of indirection by passing an anonymous function. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4967732/3595791).

Comment: Regarding the meaning of "curried": it's related to the unexplained "1" in step 4. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying : the process of turning a function which takes multiple arguments into a series of functions which take a single argument.

Comment: I found this wikipedia page while writing the answer, but it's not exactly what's being done by the code. Only the first argument is ever stripped, the function is not recursively stripping everything. 
It's also advanced mathematics which is not fit for a first introduction to javascript. I improved my description a bit to make this more clear.